# Swagger UI: Unable to infer baseurl, No Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

We are getting the unable to infer base url when we tried to access the swagger url

[image: Swagger UI Issue]

We use Spring 5.3.18 and we don't use spring security.

We are using the Spring fox 3.0.0 version, and below is the Swagger Config and Web Config code.

```
@Profile("swagger")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerConfig {

  private static final String DEFAULT = "1. Default";

  @Bean
  public Docket apiDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("basepackage.rest.controller"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
  }
}
```

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Profile("swagger")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?